# How can we hide shipping information section if a user selects pickup shipping method?

Tags: commerce

Using Commerce 2, we have created a flat rate shipping method for *Local Pickups*.

> [image: screenshot]

Since the order is not shipped for local pickups, we would like to avoid users have to enter their shipping information.

How can this be achieved?